# A slab became the death of me

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Some guidelines (I may add more for clarification if needed):

1. Each stanza indicates something about my life in the form of a clue's homophone, but that is all I will guarantee. The words in the stanza may or may not pertain to my real life events otherwise.
2. A correct answer will correctly decipher the clues provided by at least half of the stanzas.

Examples:
When he proposed, he gave me some ground wheat (flour -> flower)
I spent my life collecting tolls on the highway (fare -> fair, could mean I treated people equally, not necessarily that I was a toll collector)

> Some think of me like a necessity,
> Yet others say I'm more of an obsession.
>
> A fine wine or a strong brandy 
> My family could never afford to serve.
>
> One night, the dreams came to me.
> I awoke with the urge to be where the king exhaled.
>
> After some time in his service,
> I ended up in a gurney
>
> Not much later, they told me that I
> Was like a tributary whose flow is restricted.
>
> A slab became the death of me,
> Now my remains are one with the world
>
> Many follow me intently,
> Assuming I know nothing of it.

Who am I?

Hint:

> The clues are in more or less chronological order of my life events.

Hint (6/27/16 11:13 AM EST):

> I am a real historical figure

Hint (6/30/16 2:03 PM EST):

> I'm from the Eastern Hemisphere

Hint (7/6/16 9:18 AM EST):

> This can be (fairly) easily solved with just two clues deciphered

Hint (6/13/17 3:36 PM CT):

> I am female

Hint (6/14/17 11:41 AM CT):

> I believe that the sixth stanza is the most important; solve that, and the answer choices become very few (this is why I made it the title). 
> Think about the different ways the word slab can be used, and the different types of slabs.

Comment: Just FYI, the hint seems to be missing

Comment: @pime Unless that *is* the hint...

Comment: @Moose Are any of the homophones proper nouns, or are they all common words?

Comment: @DanRussell all are common words that can be found in the dictionary

Comment: I cant help but think of a particular TISM song when I read the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are

> [Joan of Arc](https://www.biography.com/people/joan-of-arc-9354756)

Going chronologically:

Some think of me like a necessity,
Yet others say I'm more of an obsession.

> *Really* not sure about this one, but perhaps obsession could refer to Ark of the Covenant -> Ark/Arc? Born to Jacque d'Arc

A fine wine or a strong brandy 
My family could never afford to serve.

> Pour/Poor (credit @Arth) - her family was poor. Wine may be a hat-tip to France.

One night, the dreams came to me.
I awoke with the urge to be where the king exhaled.

> Sighed/Side (credit @Arth) - Dreams = visions/prophecies, for which Joan of Arc is famous. The king would be the King of France, who she helped out militarily and with her prophecies.

After some time in his service,
I ended up in a gurney/trundle

> Cot/Caught - She was eventually captured by the English.

Not much later, they told me that I
Was like a tributary whose flow is restricted.

> Dammed/Damned (credit @Arth) - She was convicted of heresy, so damned is fitting.

A slab became the death of me,
Now my remains are one with the world

> Slab could refer to a slab of meat -> steak/stake: famously burned at the stake. One with the world could be ashes to ashes, dust to dust (ashes->burned, dust->dirt->one with the world)

Many follow me intently,
Assuming I know nothing of it.

> Tail/Tale (credit @Arth) - she's now the subject of legends/tales and many stories are told based on her life

Comment: How do you get "arc" from the first line, other than already knowing the answer?

Comment: @MikeQ Definitely wouldn't get there without working backward. In fact, I have no idea if that interpretation is actually what the OP had in mind.

Answer (score 5):

Some possibles (bold confirmed by OP):

Some think of me like a necessity,
Yet others say I'm more of an obsession.

> Need/Knead, Tic/Tick

A fine wine or a strong brandy 
My family could never afford to serve.

> **Poor/Pour**, <s>Port</s>

One night, the dreams came to me.
I awoke with the urge to be where the king exhaled.

> <s>Heir/Air.. tenuous!</s> **Side/Sighed** <s>(Regi-sighed!)</s>

After some time in his service,
I ended up in a <s>gurney</s> trundle

> Heal/Heel, Week/Weak, Borne/Born

Not much later, they told me that I
Was like a tributary whose flow is restricted.

> <s>Lock/Loch, Straight/Strait, Coarse/Course.. all tenuous! Creek/Creak,</s> **Damned/Dammed**, <s>Currant/Current</s>

A slab became the death of me,
Now my remains are one with the world

> Peace/Piece, Flaw/Floor, Board/Bored

Many follow me intently,
Assuming I know nothing of it.

> **Tale/Tail**, <s>Prophet/Profit</s>

Can't really work out how these all may fit with the narrative or a historical figure however :(

Comment: You've got the last stanza (with tail/tale) and your first idea (pour/poor) for the second stanza is correct.

Comment: You figured out stanza 3 as well (sighed/side). I changed a word in stanza 4 that should help

Comment: And 5 (Dammed/Damned). You're still missing the first and 6th, which are the two that I really consider crucial to finding the answer. You're somewhat on the right track with tic but going the wrong way with the 6th

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Mary Ward?
>  First to die in a automobile accident, and due to this laws/regulations were started. She also had published a few books.

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion? You should explain how each stanza led you to this answer

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab at the remaining clues:

1. Some think of me like a necessity,
   Yet others say I'm more of an obsession.

> Vein / Vain (veins are quite important, vanity can be seen as self-obsession)

4. After some time in his service,
   I ended up in a trundle

> Wield / Wheeled (wielding a sword; a trundle is a wheeled cart)

6. A slab became the death of me,
   Now my remains are one with the world

> Gneiss / Nice? .. ha, actual guess: Wrought / Rot (like heavy wrought iron; buried -> decomposed)

No ideas who it might be, though.